# Ajax call always returning error from mvc action even though it works fine

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-select2

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this ajax call keeps returning an error. (I'm new to the web-world, so I'm guessing I'm missing something simple here :S)

In my cshtml I have a Select2 multivalue selectbox that holds tags. Then, when I try to remove a tag by doing an ajax call down to my controller, it returns an error even though my action completes successfully:

```
  $(function () {
        $('#tagSelector').select2({
            placeholder: 'Select a tag...',
            multiple: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("SearchTags", "UnitDetails")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        searchTerm: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return { results: data };
                }
            },
            createSearchChoice: function (term) {
                return {id: term, text: term};
            }
        }).on("removed", function(e) {
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/UnitDetails/UnTagUnit/" + Model.ViewUnitContract.Id)';
            var id = e.val;
            var tagName = e.choice.text;
            console.log(id + " : " + tagName);

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { selectedItem: tagName },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function() {
                    toastr.options = {
                        "closeButton": true,
                        "debug": false,
                        "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
                        "onclick": null,
                        "showDuration": "300",
                        "hideDuration": "1000",
                        "timeOut": "3000",
                        "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                        "showEasing": "swing",
                        "hideEasing": "linear",
                        "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                        "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
                    };
                    toastr.success("Tag deleted from unit.", "Success!");
                },
                error: function() {
                    toastr.options = {
                        "closeButton": true,
                        "debug": false,
                        "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
                        "onclick": null,
                        "showDuration": "300",
                        "hideDuration": "1000",
                        "timeOut": "3000",
                        "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                        "showEasing": "swing",
                        "hideEasing": "linear",
                        "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                        "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
                    };
                    toastr.error("Could not delete tag from unit.", "Oops!");
                }
            });
        });
```

In my controller, the `UnTagUnit(int id, string selectedItem)` looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult UnTagUnit(int id, string selectedItem)
{
    try
    {
        UnitClient.UnTagUnit(id, selectedItem);

        // what to return if success?
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log and handle
        // what to return if error?
    }
}
```

As mentioned, the method works fine, by that I mean completeing the `UnTagUnit(id, selectedItem)` part successfully (wcf service).

So, I guess I'm either missing something or doing something fundamentally wrong. Also tried different approaches sucs as returning `new Json(new { success = true} )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use return `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in your action since you are using `GET` method,

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult UnTagUnit(int id, string selectedItem)
{
    try
    {
        UnitClient.UnTagUnit(id, selectedItem);

        // what to return if success?
        return   Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log and handle
        // what to return if error?
        //you can throw error here .. 
        throw ("Un tag failed "+e.Message);
       ///or return it as a message
         return   Json( new { success = false,message="Un tag failed "+e.Message} , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    }
}
```